# Caution: The Provisioning API is currently available by invitation only

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Started exploring Google Analytics API and encountered this notification:

> Caution: The Provisioning API is currently available by invitation only.

What are they warning about? What kind of invitation do you need?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are warning you not to try and use the Provisioning API unless you have been invited by Google, otherwise you may be wasting your time.

Your project needs special permission to access the Provisioning API.  You need a direct invite from the team at google.

I am going to ping google for you to see if i can get any idea of the procedures to get an invite.

## Update

The Google Analytics api team have updated the documentation.  They recommend you use the [Admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1)  which at this time is still in Alpha so be careful it's probably going to change over the next few months.

[image]

Comment: How to get this invitation?

Comment: Thats why i sent the email to find out,  I have never heard of anyone getting permission previously it was highly restricted.  HOwever with the New GA4 and the [GoogleAnalyticsAdminAPI](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_provisioning) which allows for creating GA4 accounts.  I am not sure why they would still have the Provisioning API  that allowed for creating new Universal analytics accounts protected.   Unless they really don't want people creating UA accounts.

Comment: Now I understand, I will be grateful for the information as soon as you get an answer!

Comment: The team is west cost USA so hang in there may take a little while.

Comment: I heard back from the team they have updated the documentation. They recommend you use the [Admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1)

Comment: Thank you! What about Universal Analytics?

Comment: I think that's kind of the point they don't want you creating new UA accounts only GA4,  GA4 is the way forward, the future, and the source of all truth.

Comment: Not really I just told you not to use something :)